# How to Make Div fill the remaining space?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a grid layout, but I want the div to fill all the white space and not just side by side. I've tried everything to my knowledge, and I just cant figure it out. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3s6b8dm/2/

If you look, the .sml on the right is supposed to be 4 squares, but only 2 are put, then it goes to the next line. It messes up the whole grid this way.

How I would like it to look like for blending:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEdCT.png)

```css
body {
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.sml {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.med {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.big {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.feat {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.med {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.big {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.feat {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1x1");
  border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<body><div class="feat"></div><div class="big"></div><div class="big"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="med"></div><div class="med"></div><div class="med"></div><div class="med"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div><div class="sml"></div>
```

Comment: What happens if you change either the width or height to `100%`?

Comment: `body` width 1200px? Why you don't want to make your website responsive? Elements with fixed width? But why? `inline-block` DIVs? Oh no... you should rethink what you're doing - It helps taking a look how other solved grid layouts...

Comment: How do you want it to look? If you have a `200x200` square, you won't be able to have it fill space next to a `300x300` without having it distorted.

Comment: What would be the best way to achieve this would you guys think?

Comment: @blackandorangecat I want it to flow into the design, I thought this was the best way to approach this, but now I'm thinking other wise.

Comment: I think what you want is the flexible boxes approach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: Curtis, there are several ways to approach your problem and using `inline-block`s is not one of them. You can use flexbox, masonry, the so-called "pintrest layout" or the "metro layout" techniques. With a polyfill, you could also use the CSS grid technique. But at this point your research effort seems close to `null` and it also looks like you are trying a simplistic approach to a fairly complex problem. You have a lot to read before you can solve this problem and asking others to do it for you is not exactly in accordance with [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the pattern depicted in the image you provided, verses the code, the dimensions do not match. The ratios are:

#### Image

- `.sml` 1x1
- `.med` 2x2
- `.big` 3x3

#### CSS

- `.sml` 1x1
- `.med` 1.5x1.5
- `.big` 2x2

I assume that you wanted what's in the image, so I changed the dimensions according to the ratios shown in the image. I also scaled down everything to 20% (multiply by 5 to original size) for easier viewing of Snippet.

Additional flex-containers* were wrapped around the squares:

- `section.col1`
- `section.col2`
- `section.col3`
- `section.sub2`

Body was given `display:flex` as well. Although in the future I would advise against using body in a limited fashion. Instead of giving body a fixed width, wrap everything in another element instead. Another thing you should consider is not to use fixed dimensions for layout. Try relative units `em` and/or percentages, as well as a little bit of intrinsic types such as `vw` and `vh`. The default browser ratio for `px` to `em` is 16:1 (for every `16px` = `1em`). In the Snippet, you could make the whole thing responsive by converting the `px` to `em`.

> `.sml {width:2.5em; height:2.5em;....`

and replace the body with another element.

> `main {width:15em....`

**SNIPPET**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sub2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sml {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/40x40/f00/fff?text=40x40")no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.med {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/80x80/fc0/000?text=80x80")no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.big {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/120x120/000/fc0?text=120x120")no-repeat;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.feat {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/240x80/00f/000?text=280x80")no-repeat;
  width: 280px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="feat"></div>
  <section class='col1'>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="med"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
  </section>
  <section class='col2'>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <section class='sub2'>
      <div class="sml"></div>
      <div class="sml"></div>
    </section>
    <div class="med"></div>
  </section>
  <section class='col3'>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
    <div class="sml"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

`*` flex containers: A term to refer to an element that has the property `display:flex` which influences all of it's children elements (called flex items) to adhere to flexbox layout rules.